# XmlReader.ReadToNextSibling not working

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I'm trying to read an xml document but the XmlReader.ReadToNextSibling does not work as advertised on this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7w4zx9.aspx)

Here is a console example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlText = "<xmlRoot><group><item>Item 1</item><item>Item 2</item></group><group><item>Item 3</item><item>Item 4</item></group></xmlRoot>";

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlText)))
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("item");
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", reader.ReadInnerXml());
                } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("item"));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

This only outputs one item:

> Item: Item 1

**Anyone know how i can get this to work?**

Please do not suggest using DOM model (XmlDocument). I cannot because these xml files are from different sources and can have many different namespaces and is a huge hassle. I need to get this working.

Comment: How come "many namespaces" is a reason not to use a DOM? The newer XDocument (FX3.5 +) makes working with namespaces a lot easier than it used to be.

Comment: hmm actually, you're right.. that XElement.Parse is pretty awesome... i think i'm going with it. (+1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `ReadInnerXml` also advances the reader. So when you get to your first `ReadToNextSibling`, you are positioned on Item 2, and there is no next sibling.

This code will read both your items:

```
string xmlText = "<xmlRoot><group><item>Item 1</item><item>Item 2</item></group><group><item>Item 3</item><item>Item 4</item></group></xmlRoot>";

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlText)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("item");
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", reader.ReadInnerXml());
    } while (reader.Name == "item");
}
```